# Dropdown list selected value is not updating in UI knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, knockout.js

In my application, I am having a table and when selected a row it shows its details (with more options in addition to the data in the table).

When a edit button is clicked, it show the editable page in which i can edit in testboxes and dropdown list.

Here, when i edit values in text box, the value is updating in the UI that is in non editable form.

But when i change the drop down list, the updated value is not showing up in non editable form. It shows only the old value.

Here is my dropdown list html.

```
<select id="ddlType" data-bind="options: $root.ddlTypes, optionsText: 'OppType', optionsValue: 'ID', optionsCaption: 'Select..', value: selectedTypeId"></select>
```

The drop down list is being binded from web api.

Please let me know, where Iam going wrong..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your variable as observable like

this.selectedTypeId = ko.observable();

and while using this variable in HTML use $root/$parent according to context.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, selectedTypeId must be observable in viewmodel, so that the changes on this will automatically update UI.

this.selectedTypeId = ko.observable();